# LinQ LIKE operator

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, sql-like

I need help with using a normal SQL LIKE %% operator within a LINQ query.

This is the data for row called **Type** (thats returned from the normal query without the like operator):

```
Independent Contractor
Lease Program 
Teams
Teams interested
```

And this is my (attempted) LINQ query:

```
Public Shared Function SelectActiveByState(
    ByVal state_abbr As String, 
    ByVal catagory As String) As List(Of theLocations)

    Dim db As New MasterData
    db.CommandTimeout = 240

    Try            
        Return ( _
            From hl In db.Locations _
            Where hl.Active = True _
            And ( _
                hl.State = state_abbr Or _
                hl.AlternateLocation.Contains(state_abbr) And _
                hl.Type.Contains("/" & catagory & "/") _
            ) _
            Order By hl.Type Select hl).ToList()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

If i leave out the **And hl.Type.Contains("/" & catagory & "/")** the query works just fine (returns 4 records). But when i add that part it returns the same records regardless of my like operator.

Comment: Do you really have two fields `_Type` and `Type`? Are you getting them confused?

Comment: Just corrected that @RB. See updated OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using some of @Yaqub Ahmad code:

```
Public Shared Function SelectActiveByState(
    ByVal state_abbr As String, 
    ByVal catagory As String) As List(Of theLocations)

    Dim db As New MasterData
    db.CommandTimeout = 240

    Try            
        Return ( _
            From hl In db.Locations _
            Where hl.Active = True _
            And ( _
                (hl.State = state_abbr Or _
                hl.AlternateLocation.Contains(state_abbr)) And _
                System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.Like(hl.Type, "%" & category & "%") _
            ) _
            Order By hl.Type Select hl).ToList()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
hl.Type.Contains("/" & catagory & "/")
```

try this:

```
SqlMethods.Like(hl.Type, "%"& category &"%")
```

**EDIT**:

I am not good with VB.Net syntax.

**EDIT:**

Actually the result sql of your LINQ query becomes:

```
SELECT *
FROM   myTable
WHERE  State = state_abbr OR
       AlternateLocation LIKE state_abbr AND
       Type LIKE category
```

BUT you need this i guess:

```
SELECT *
FROM   myTable
WHERE  (State = state_abbr OR
       AlternateLocation LIKE state_abbr) AND
       Type LIKE category
```

Try this:

```
Return ( _ 
    From hl In db.Locations _ 
    Where hl.Active = True _ 
    And ( _ 
        (hl.State = state_abbr Or _ 
        hl.AlternateLocation.Contains(state_abbr)) And _ 
        SqlMethods.Like(hl.Type, "%"& category &"%") _ 
    ) _ 
    Order By hl.Type Select hl).ToList()
```

Comment: **SqlMethods.Like** does not seem to be a part of my project to be able to be used.

Comment: **System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.Like**

Comment: Still getting the same results. All records instead of 2.

Comment: What value do you have in catagory?

Comment: Thats what i had in my OP in your **EDIT #2**

Comment: You mean you have already tried this solution & it not works??

Comment: Look the problem is somewhere here
state = state_abbr OR AlternateLocation.Contains(state_abbr)

Actually it returns TRUE & so all other conditions are not conisdered.  I means the "Type LIKE category" is ignored at all.

Comment: I finally got it! Thanks for the help!